# Uploading Image to Parse(Back4App) in PHP

Tags: php

Hello everyone I'm trying to upload an image to parse with PHP. i was able to add the object all the columns works perfectly except the Image Column stays undefined i checked the php.ini (url_fopen:On ;) and the utf-8 charset and many other solutions i thins its a problem of security or Privilege !! Please if you have any useful Ideas share it and Thanks in Advance !!! 
Here is my code

```
<?php 

require_once( 'autoload.php' ); 
// Add the "use" declarations where you'll be using the classes
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud;
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseQuery;

try {
    $app_id     = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ;
    $rest_key   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $master_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );
    ParseClient::setServerURL('https://parseapi.back4app.com', '/');


if(isset($_GET['libelle']) && (isset($_GET['prix']) ) ){
    $libelle = $_GET['libelle'];
    $prix = $_GET['prix'];
}

if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) {
    $isFileExists = file_exists ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] );
    $isGoodSize = ($_FILES['image']['size'] < 600000) && ($_FILES['image']['size'] > 0);

    if ( $isFileExists && $isGoodSize) {
  // save file to Parse
        $file = ParseFile::createFromData( file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), $_FILES['image']['name']  );
        $file->save();
        //echo 'File URL: <a href="' . $file->getURL() . '" target="_blank">' . $file->getURL() . '</a>';
    } else {
        echo "Erreur";
    }
}


$Prod = ParseObject::create("Produit");
//$Prod = new ParseObject("Produit");
$Prod->set("libelle",$libelle);
$Prod->set("prix",(float)$prix);

if ( isset( $file ) ) {
    $Prod->set("image",$file);
}


try {

    $Prod->save();
    echo 'Object Saved with ID: <strong>' . $Prod->getObjectId() . '</strong>.<br/>';

} catch (ParseException $ex) {  

    echo 'Failed to create new object, with error message: ' . $ex->getMessage();
}

} catch (ParseException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
} 


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was checking here more about files! Just for help you, the maximum file size is 20MB. You can test with different file sizes.
At releases page on GitHub from [Parse PHP SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-php-sdk/releases), you can check the version 1.2.8 that fixed a error with ParseFiles.